# Sort the Linked list

Tags: sorting, hadoop

I have linked list with 300 nodes.I want to sort that linked list using hadoop .

And scenario is, you need to  store 100 nodes on each linked list and have to sort internally on each machine and later master node will give final linked list with  300 nodes in sorted order.

And let suppose ,if  100th nodes of one machine have value 23 and 2 is stored on one machine and 3 is stored on other machine .then how should we tackle this situation

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if you run insertion sort after each individual linked list (of 100 members) is sorted.